# WordPress search is not working with more than 2 characters

Tags: wordpress, search

I have created a custom template for search our products with lots of filters and one input field to search with characters. However, it works only with one or two characters like "a", "ag" but not with more than two characters. If I search for something like "pol" or "polar" it redirects me to WordPress 404 - PAGE NOT FOUND.

**Update:**

I have tried two solutions: one with the custom query ajax and that works fine with a search but the only problem I faced is with the pagination; the other one used WordPress standard query object, it works well with pagination but I'm getting a problem with search character length. Below are the two attempts that I tried.

**Attempt #1**: with the Ajax. this code is written down in function.php file

```
function get_search_results()
{
    global $wpdb;

    if(!empty($_POST['search_input'])) {
        $search_input = $_POST['search_input'];

        $where = 'pm.meta_value LIKE '. "'%".$search_input."%'".' AND pm.meta_key LIKE "%pattern_number"';
        $where1 = 'p.post_title LIKE '."'%".$search_input."%'".' AND p.post_type = "product"';

        $search_sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT(pm.post_id), ph.lightness, ph.color_label FROM wp_posts p 
                                INNER JOIN wp_products_huecolor ph on p.ID = ph.post_id
                                INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id 
                                WHERE p.post_status = "publish" AND p.post_type = "product" AND (('.$where.') OR ('.$where1.')) ORDER BY ph.color_label, ph.lightness ASC';

        $total_query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (${search_sql}) AS combined_table";
        $total = $wpdb->get_var( $total_query );
        $items_per_page = 10;
        $page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
        $offset = ( $page * $items_per_page ) - $items_per_page;
        $page = $wpdb->get_results( $search_sql.' LIMIT '.$offset.', '.$items_per_page );


       //echo "SQL = ".$wpdb->last_query; wp_die();
       echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($page as $object)
        {
            // get custom fields values related to a post by post id
            $fields = get_fields($object->post_id);

            // get post details by post id
            $post_detail =  get_post($object->post_id, $object );

            $brand_name = $fields[brand]->name;
            $full_sheet_image = $fields[full_sheet_image][sizes][thumbnail];
            $post_title = $post_detail->post_title;
            $post_name = $post_detail->post_name;

        ?>

    <li class="post-pattern">
        <div class="search-productsBoxSecond">
            <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo site_url( '/products/'.$post_name.'', 'http' ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $full_sheet_image; ?>" alt="" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-full"></a>
            <div class="search-productNameSecond"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo site_url( '/products/'.$post_name.'', 'http' ); ?>"><?php echo $post_title; ?></a></div>
            <div class="search-productBrandSecond"><?php echo $brand_name; ?></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '<div class="search-product-navigation">';
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%', site_url( '/pattern-search/' ) ),
            'format' => '',
            'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
            'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
            'total' => ceil($total / $items_per_page),
            'current' => $page
        ));
        echo '</div>';

    }
    exit();
}


add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_featured_products','filter_featured_products');
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_featured_products','filter_featured_products');
```

**Attempt #2**: with Standard WP_Query in the custom template.

```
<?php 

$args = array();
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$search_keywords = ( get_query_var( 's' ) ) ? get_query_var( 's' ) : ""; 
if(isset($search_keywords) && $search_keywords != ''){
    $args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'product',
            'search_prod_title' => $search_keywords,
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'    => 10,
            'paged'             => $paged,
            'wildcard_on_key'   => true,
            'meta_query'        => array(
                                    array(
                                        'key'       => 'product_type_%_pattern_number',
                                        'value'     => $search_keywords,
                                        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
                                    ),
            )
        );
}else{
    $args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'product',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'    => 10,
            'paged'             => $paged
        );
}


// query for getting featured product
add_filter( 'posts_fields', 'products_posts_select_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'posts_join', 'products_posts_join_filter', 10, 2 );    
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'title_filter', 10, 2 ); 
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'products_posts_orderby', 10, 2 ); 
add_filter('posts_groupby', 'products_posts_groupby', 10, 2);
$sql_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

//echo $wpdb->last_query; die();
//echo '<pre>'; print_r($sql_query); die;
//echo $sql_query->request; die;
remove_filter( 'posts_fields', 'products_posts_select_filter', 10, 2 );
remove_filter( 'posts_join', 'products_posts_join_filter', 10, 2 );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'title_filter', 10, 2 );
remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'products_posts_posts_orderby', 10, 2 ); 
remove_filter('posts_groupby', 'products_posts_groupby', 10, 2);
if( $sql_query->have_posts()):
    echo '<ul>';
    while( $sql_query->have_posts()): $sql_query->the_post();
    {
        //get custom fields meta values related to a post
        $fields = get_fields($post->ID);
        $full_sheet_image = $fields[full_sheet_image][sizes][thumbnail];

        //echo'<pre>'; print_r($post_detail); die;
?>

        <li class="post-pattern">
            <div class="search-productsBoxSecond">
                <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo site_url( '/products/'.$post->post_name.'', 'http' ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $full_sheet_image; ?>" alt="" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-full"></a>
                <div class="search-productNameSecond"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo site_url( '/products/'.$post->post_name.'', 'http' ); ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a></div>
                <div class="search-productBrandSecond"><?php echo $fields[brand]->name; ?></div>
            </div>
        </li>

<?php
    }
    endwhile; ?>

    </ul>

    <!-- pagination -->
    <div class="search-product-navigation">
        <?php
              echo paginate_links(array(
                'total' => $sql_query->max_num_pages
              ));
        ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

here are the filter functions thats written in the function.php

```
/*Replaced meta_key = with meta_key LIKE */
add_filter( 'posts_where', function ( $where, \WP_Query $q )
{ 
    // Check for our custom query var
    if ( true !== $q->get( 'wildcard_on_key' ) )
        return $where;

    // Lets filter the clause
    $where = str_replace( 'meta_key =', 'meta_key LIKE', $where );

    return $where;
}, 10, 2 );

function title_filter( $where, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $search_term = $wp_query->get( 'search_prod_title' ) ) { 
        $post_title_clause = '('.$wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( like_escape( $search_term ) ) . '%\') OR';
        $where = substr_replace($where, $post_title_clause , 6, 0);
    }
    return $where;
}

function products_posts_select_filter( $fields, &$wp_query ){

    $fields = 'DISTINCT(wp_posts.ID), wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_name, ph.lightness, ph.color_label';
    return $fields;

}

function products_posts_join_filter( $join, &$wp_query ){

    $join .= " INNER JOIN wp_products_huecolor ph on wp_posts.ID = ph.post_id";
    return $join ;

}

function products_posts_orderby( $orderby, &$wp_query ){

    $orderby = 'ph.color_label, ph.lightness ASC';
    return $orderby;    

}

function products_posts_groupby( $groupby, &$wp_query ){

    return $groupby = '';

}
```

Comment: Can you please share the custom template with its filters?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that you are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting a question. This will increase your chance of getting help. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stevish. I have tried to add my code in the comment but it's not allowing me to add entire code so added as an answer below.